# Javascript Auto Form submission not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have following simple HTML Form & i tried to submit the form automatically during page load.
Below Javascript code is not automatically submitting the form.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="SSL.php" method="POST" name="TForm" id="transactionForm">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantTxnId" id="merchantTxnId" value="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
Redirecting ... Please wait...
```

**Java script:**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        alert(1); // this is working..
            document.getElementById("transactionForm").submit(); //nothing is happening with this line . form is not getting submitted
    }
</script>
```

**I found following error in Chrome console mode says:** 
[image]
Kindly suggest me where the problem is...

Comment: define `not working`. Are errors thrown in console? WHat happens within page etc

Comment: @charlietfl : Nothing is happening after alert. same screen

Comment: Open up the JavaScript console, there might be some errors.

Comment: @VedantTerkar: its copy paste error. I corrected my question. ya alert is working

Comment: @Nathan : where i can see JavaScript console ?

Comment: @logan use `ctr+shift+k` in firefox, `F12` in chrome and IE 10+. for `console`.

Comment: @logan If you're using Chrome on Windows it's `F12` but if you're on Mac it's `Command+Shift+I`.

Comment: @Nathan : Thanks. I put a snapshot of Chrome F12 .. pls see the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not use `submit` as the `name` or `id` of any of your form elements.

The reason is, that you can reach each child of your form via `document.getElementById('form').nameOfTheChild` where `nameOfTheChild` is the `name` of the child. If you have a child with the name `submit`, `document.getElementById('form').submit` is a shortcut to address that child.

The documentation of `.submit()` says that :

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that
>   conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.

Comment: then what is the solution ?

Comment: @logan Change the id and name of the input to something else.

Comment: @logan the answer is true...the documentation of .submit() states that "Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures."